# How to find root cause which results in my ubuntu 12.04 suddenly reboot frequently while I using make to compile?

Tags: 12.04, boot, compiling, reboot

When I was using make to compile my source code, the ubuntu reboot suddenly, after reboot and re-compile for a while, the ubuntu reboot again, this problem frequently occurred these two days, and I had to break the compiling, the lasted one occurred this morning and today I have no more compiling.
How to find root cause to resolve this fatal issue?

Or from where can I start to diagnose?

Yesterday I suspected the memory had run out, and the top before reboot,

```
top - 20:20:28 up 30 min,  3 users,  load average: 1.63, 1.18, 0.86
Tasks: 176 total,   1 running, 174 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 55.6%us,  1.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 42.0%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.6%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1974116k total,  1766708k used,   207408k free,    18812k buffers
Swap:  1998844k total,    31496k used,  1967348k free,   697752k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                           
17811 victor    20   0 1557m  82m 9692 S  263  4.3   0:08.10 javac                                                                             
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.39 kworker/1:0                                                                       
   54 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.32 kworker/3:1                                                                       
 1115 root      20   0  154m  36m 8120 S    0  1.9   0:36.17 Xorg                                                                              
 1938 victor    20   0 1128m  70m  32m S    0  3.6   0:15.63 compiz                                                                            
 1947 victor    20   0 20180  932  760 S    0  0.0   0:00.80 syndaemon                                                                         
 2097 victor    20   0  513m  18m  10m S    0  0.9   0:21.30 gnome-terminal                                                                    
    1 root      20   0 24560 1836 1372 S    0  0.1   0:00.63 init                                                                              
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                          
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.61 ksoftirqd/0                                                                       
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/0                                                                       
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                        
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/1                                                                       
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.79 ksoftirqd/1                                                                       
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                        
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.32 migration/2                                                                       
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.56 ksoftirqd/2                                                                       
   15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2                                                                        
   16 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.25 migration/3                                                                       
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.56 ksoftirqd/3                                                                       
   19 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3                                                                        
   20 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset                                                                            
   21 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                           
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                         
   23 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                             
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sync_supers                                                                       
   26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default                                                                       
   27 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                       
   28 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                           
   30 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                           
   31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                             
   32 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 md
```

It seems has no problem about memory and cpu schedule.

It seems the cpu temperature was not the root cause, the cpu temperature was not too high before rebooting.

```
Sat Aug 31 17:08:41 CST 2013
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +83.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:         514 RPM
temp1:        +77.0°C
temp2:        +83.0°C
temp3:        +77.0°C
temp4:         +0.0°C
temp5:         +0.0°C
temp6:         +0.0°C
temp7:        +33.0°C
temp8:         +0.0°C
temp9:        +77.0°C
temp10:       +66.0°C
temp11:        -4.0°C
temp12:       +77.0°C
temp13:       +77.0°C
temp14:        +0.0°C
temp15:        +0.0°C
temp16:        +0.0°C

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +78.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +77.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

These logs,

/var/log/syslog

```
Aug 31 10:12:47 ThinkPad-Edge rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="853" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Aug 31 10:14:04 ThinkPad-Edge anacron[2608]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Aug 31 10:14:06 ThinkPad-Edge AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Aug 31 10:14:06 ThinkPad-Edge AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Aug 31 10:17:01 ThinkPad-Edge CRON[3608]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 31 10:17:35 ThinkPad-Edge anacron[2608]: Job `cron.weekly' started
Aug 31 10:17:35 ThinkPad-Edge anacron[3780]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2013-08-31
Aug 31 10:19:19 ThinkPad-Edge anacron[2608]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Aug 31 10:19:19 ThinkPad-Edge anacron[2608]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
Aug 31 17:05:01 ThinkPad-Edge dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.3 from 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 (android-613ef32c24ca718e) via wlan1
Aug 31 17:05:01 ThinkPad-Edge dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.3 to 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 (android-613ef32c24ca718e) via wlan1
Aug 31 17:05:01 ThinkPad-Edge dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.3 from 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 (android-613ef32c24ca718e) via wlan1
Aug 31 17:05:01 ThinkPad-Edge dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.3 to 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 (android-613ef32c24ca718e) via wlan1
Aug 31 17:08:18 ThinkPad-Edge hostapd: wlan1: STA 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 WPA: group key handshake completed (RSN)
Aug 31 17:08:18 ThinkPad-Edge hostapd: wlan1: STA 88:53:d4:26:c4:14 WPA: received EAPOL-Key 2/2 Group with unexpected replay counter
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="799" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.5.0-39-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #60~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:38:41 UTC 2013 (Ubuntu 3.5.0-39.60~precise1-generic 3.5.7.17)
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-39-generic root=UUID=2b1c65df-1673-4613-ae42-03f9ac0df181 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

```
[  1816.518] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "LEN", prod id 16544
[  1816.518] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1816.518] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   69.30  1366 1398 1422 1470  768 771 775 785 -hsync -vsync (47.1 kHz eP)
[  1816.518] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   57.70  1366 1398 1422 1470  768 771 775 785 -hsync -vsync (39.3 kHz e)
[ 22674.104] (II) config/udev: removing device MLK rapoo 7100
[ 22674.422] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Close
[ 22674.557] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 22677.184] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MLK rapoo 7100 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 22677.250] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22677.250] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22677.250] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MLK rapoo 7100 (/dev/input/event6)
[ 22677.250] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 22677.250] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[ 22677.250] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'MLK rapoo 7100'
[ 22677.250] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: always reports core events
[ 22677.250] (**) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Vendor 0x1bcf Product 0x501
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found 9 mouse buttons
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found scroll wheel(s)
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found relative axes
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found x and y relative axes
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found absolute axes
[ 22677.327] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[ 22677.327] (--) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Found keys
[ 22677.327] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Configuring as mouse
[ 22677.327] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Configuring as keyboard
[ 22677.328] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: Adding scrollwheel support
[ 22677.328] (**) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 22677.328] (**) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 22677.328] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.4/2-1.2.4:1.0/input/input15/event6"
[ 22677.328] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MLK rapoo 7100" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[ 22677.328] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[ 22677.328] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 22677.328] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 22677.362] (II) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: initialized for relative axes.
[ 22677.362] (WW) evdev: MLK rapoo 7100: ignoring absolute axes.
[ 22677.362] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 22677.362] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 22677.362] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 22677.362] (**) MLK rapoo 7100: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

/var/log/kern.log

```
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.342799] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1403, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.342808] select 7065 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 10269, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.342819] send sigkill to 7065 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 10269
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.344223] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1403, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.344230] select 7070 (VC manager), adj 300, size 10323, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.344239] send sigkill to 7070 (VC manager), adj 300, size 10323
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.347269] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1403, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:34 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26657.350905] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1403, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.127569] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1403, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.127582] select 10048 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1578, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.127590] send sigkill to 10048 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1578
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.131328] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1379, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.131338] select 10051 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1627, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.131348] send sigkill to 10051 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1627
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.133869] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1379, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.141198] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1379, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.144465] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1379, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.146763] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1376, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.148907] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1375, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.150934] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1375, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.153567] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1375, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.505539] select 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1375, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.505558] send sigkill to 4510 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1375
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.506585] select 4515 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1391, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:36 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.506594] send sigkill to 4515 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1391
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.743841] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9577, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.743848] select 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1271, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.743853] select 9946 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1298, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.743865] send sigkill to 9946 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1298
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.744735] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9577, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.744739] select 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1271, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.744743] select 9949 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1328, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.744750] send sigkill to 9949 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1328
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.745656] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9577, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.745661] select 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1271, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.748133] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9577, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26660.748138] select 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1271, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.152084] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9536, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.152089] select 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1252, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.152099] send sigkill to 6160 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1252
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.227827] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.227832] select 6163 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1302, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.227839] send sigkill to 6163 (VC manager), adj 300, size 1302
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.445887] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.446815] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.447733] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.448550] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.450389] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9535, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.451737] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9530, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.453348] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.461250] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:37 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.462497] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.745699] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.745710] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.745714] select 10206 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1229, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26661.745725] send sigkill to 10206 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1229
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.154626] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.154633] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.154635] select 10208 (Chrome_ChildIOT), adj 300, size 1286, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.154641] send sigkill to 10208 (Chrome_ChildIOT), adj 300, size 1286
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.155208] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.155211] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.155735] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.155738] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.156287] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.156289] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.156859] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.156861] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.157419] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.157422] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.157968] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.157971] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.158505] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.158507] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.159109] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.159112] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.159658] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.159660] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.160547] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.160550] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.161541] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.161544] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.162544] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9528, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.162547] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.163848] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9524, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.163851] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1223, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.164953] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9514, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.164957] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.166131] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9513, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.166134] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.167192] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9513, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.167196] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.168686] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9513, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.168694] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.170744] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9509, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.170750] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.247095] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9459, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:38 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.247103] select 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1221, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.247113] send sigkill to 9960 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1221
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.469810] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9454, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.469820] select 9985 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1140, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.469829] send sigkill to 9985 (chromium-browse), adj 300, size 1140
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.470865] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9454, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.470871] select 9987 (Chrome_ChildIOT), adj 300, size 1222, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.470878] send sigkill to 9987 (Chrome_ChildIOT), adj 300, size 1222
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.472783] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9395, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.474938] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9380, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.477981] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9380, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.479629] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9378, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.641492] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9370, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.805430] select 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9366, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.805441] send sigkill to 6129 (chromium-browse), adj 100, size 9366
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.806057] select 6131 (dconf worker), adj 100, size 9555, to kill
Aug 31 17:01:39 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [26662.806063] send sigkill to 6131 (dconf worker), adj 100, size 9555
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.5.0-39-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #60~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:38:41 UTC 2013 (Ubuntu 3.5.0-39.60~precise1-generic 3.5.7.17)
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-39-generic root=UUID=2b1c65df-1673-4613-ae42-03f9ac0df181 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Aug 31 17:09:47 ThinkPad-Edge kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009c3ff] usable
```

Comment: You can use `htop` or System Monitor to keep an eye on memory and CPU usage during the compilation. Also have you checked your computer is not getting too hot during compilation and just reboots because of that?

Comment: @Salem How to monitor or observe the cpu temperature?

Comment: You can use `sensors` command (`lm-sensors` package).

Comment: @Salem I found the cpu temperatures is not too high before ubuntu reboot.

Answer (score 2):

After a crash, do you see any clues in the following files:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/dmesg`
- `/var/log/dmesg.0`
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`

Comment: I couldn't find any useful info from these logs.

Comment: try to look in the kernel log or post it here `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: @Tarun The kernel log is so long that i only can post it limited.

Comment: after the system reboots do the following `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and post its output.

Comment: @Tarun I post the kernel log which time located nearby the rebooting time, the ubuntu reboot at Sat Aug 31 17:08:46 CST 2013